# How to limit what is shown in WebStorm's auto completion?

Tags: javascript, ide, webstorm

I am working on a Sencha project and would like to see only Sencha/ ExtJS completion suggestions. Currently, I get a really long list of suggestions.

[image]

I'd like to see the completion list filtered to things that have that green leaf (Sencha) icon and no icon.